# Openstreetmap (Overpass API): Get nearest Node with a special tag

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I got a point on my map and now I'm just trying to get the name of the city (or suburb) in which the point is. My first attempt was like this:

```
<query type="node">
   <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
      <has-kv k="place" v="suburb"/>
</query>
<print/>
```

But this won't work for me, if the suburb-node isn't in my bounding-box. Is there something like an around-, nearest- or is-in-condition to get this node?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the city, country or an otherwise named place a given coordinate is in, then you are better of using a geocoder. [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) provides geocoding capabilities based on OSM data.

To answer your original question: If the feature you are searching for is not inside the bounding box, then you can of course just try extending the bounding box. But there is also an [around](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Around) keyword for searching [something near something else](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Something_near_something_else). Note that this will return *all* data matching the given tags, not just the closest one to your given point. Furthermore because Overpass is not a geocoder it won't work correctly for features mapped as an [area](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way#Area) or [relation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) instead of a simple [node](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node).

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look on Nominatim =)
It's sadly a way to laborious to use Overpass here in the way you described :\